# Initializr Bootstrap 3.1.1 - Form labels and inputs height not matching

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a small website using the basic Initializr-Bootstrap 3.1.1 website template.

I use the following sample code to display a simple form: label and input field.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label col-xs-2">Email</label>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label col-xs-2">Password</label>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

But I get this in Firefox:

http://vilela.co/images/bootstrap-form.jpg

Labels elements do not have the same height as input elements. Is there anything I can do to fix this without playing with the bootstrap css?

Seems like older versions of Bootstrap didn't have this issue.

Comment: Found the issue. I had grid.css in my code which formatted my labels and inputs with border and colors seen above. Now what confuses me, is that I can still use grid elements (rows, columns), without having grid.css included in my code, and it generates a nice grid, without the formatting (see colors/borders from image above). I thought grid.css was mandatory to use grid elements. Guess not.